# Does someone know of a website that keeps track of a species population?

Tags: population-dynamics

I am planning on doing some math on population growth, but I need a reliable source of data on population growth of some species over time. Does anyone know of a resource (website/publications/public repository) that has such information?

Comment: Why a website rather than a publication who kept track of population size over time? What kind of population dynamic are you looking for (exponential growth, logistic growth, stable population size, decreasing population size, ...). Any species of preference?

Comment: A publication or such would work, as long as I can get my hands on it. I prefer logistic growth, but the others would do just fine as it does not really influence my purpose.

Comment: Humans are currently going through a logistic looking growth, where the peak of growth (growth of $r$) has been reached in the 1970s. Those would be easy data to find and always pleasant to play with.

Answer (score 2):

**How about human?**

You will find the data of human population growth on [the webpage "Our World in Data"](https://ourworldindata.org/world-population-growth). Scroll to the second graph, click on the tab "data" and download the .csv file.

**Just google for any specific species of interest**

Otherwise you can just google things of interest. Look for large emblematic mammals or commercially important species.

- If you google "bald eagle population growth", you will easily find [these data](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://www.fws.gov/midwest/eagle/images/baea_prs_chart63to06.gif&imgrefurl=https://www.fws.gov/midwest/eagle/population/chtofprs.html&h=407&w=671&tbnid=NYEBmfUkvFV8aM:&q=eagle%20population%20over%20time&tbnh=130&tbnw=213&usg=AI4_-kSegTh8dVfZutJqvEj0sf4uFIiVEQ&vet=12ahUKEwizt8abwfDfAhXcHzQIHdnNCwUQ9QEwAHoECAcQBg..i&docid=rWARElCYu1RWvM&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizt8abwfDfAhXcHzQIHdnNCwUQ9QEwAHoECAcQBg).
- If you google "moose growth population breeding pairs", you will find [these data](https://www.google.com/search?q=moose%20growth%20population%20breeding%20pairs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9_sO4wfDfAhWQHjQIHbSaBEEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1280&bih=667).
- If you google "killer whale population growth", you will find [these data](https://www.google.com/search?q=killer%20whale%20population%20growth&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-mp70wfDfAhUmHDQIHUAsBZYQ_AUIDygC&biw=1280&bih=667).
- If you google "tuna population growth", you will find [these data](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=667&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=HTM-XOGfBoTd9AOj1pfoCg&q=tuna%20population%20growth&oq=tuna%20population%20growth&gs_l=img.3...250518.253426..253572...0.0..0.92.738.12......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0j0i67j0i30j0i5i30j0i24.BIVAEpVj2G8#imgrc=WSt5SuP3XAuenM:).

**COMADRE**

[COMADRE](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2015/09/29/027821) is a database of animal [matrix population models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_population_models). It can be of interest to you.

Comment: Can we ask for resource names on Biology SE like the one asked here?

Comment: I think you can, yes. As long as what you're looking for is well defined. I am a bit confused by your comment. Are Anonymous and BrianBlumberg the same person or did you forget the hyperlink on the word "here"?

Comment: No, that is not me. Thanks for the information.  Do you know of other sources which provide information on the population number of other species/organisms?

Comment: @BrianBlumberg Please see edited answer.